# Bubbling event from Class inside a Widget?

Tags: javascript, widget, yui, yui3, event-bubbling

I desperately try to fire an event from a class I wrote. I use this class inside my YUI Widget and I want my YUI widget to respond to the fired Event.
I know how event Bubbling is working, so this code here is working absolutely fine:

```
    YUI().use('event-custom', 'node', function (Y) {

function Publisher(bubbleTo) {
        this.addTarget(bubbleTo);
        this.publish("testEvent", {
            emitFacade: true
        });
        this.fire("testEvent");
}

function BubbleTarget() {

    this.on("testEvent", function (e) {Y.log("Bubbling in Test.js succeed!")});
    var newPublisher = new Publisher(this);
}
// To fire events or be a bubble target, augment a class with EventTarget
Y.augment(Publisher, Y.EventTarget);
Y.augment(BubbleTarget, Y.EventTarget);

var bubbleTarget = new BubbleTarget();});
```

However, as I try to apply this concept to my Widget I fail very hard.

```
YUI.add("SlideShow", function(Y) {

function SlideShow(config) {
    SlideShow.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

SlideShow.NAME = "SlideShow";

Y.extend(SlideShow, Y.Widget, {
    initializer: function() {   
        Y.log("Widget loaded!");
        this.on("testEvent", function () {
                Y.log("This should, but won't appear despite how hard I try!");
          });
    },

    renderUI: function(){
        var testSlide = new Slide("text", this);
    }
});

Y.SlideShow = SlideShow;

function Slide(sendTo)
{
this.addTarget(sendTo);
    this.publish("testEvent", {
        defaultFn: function(){Y.log('Event published.')},
        emitFacade: true
    });
    this.fire("testEvent");
}

Y.augment(Slide,Y.EventTarget, true, null, {emitFacade: true});
}, "0.0.1", {requires:["widget","event-custom","node","anim"]});
```

The Log-Output in Chromium is:

- Bubbling in Test.js succeed!
- Widget loaded!
- Event published.

It seems like I really miss something essential about Widgets. Please help me in order to better understand this subject.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in Mitch's post I think. You need to prefix the event on the bubble target subscription. So rather than:

```
this.on("testEvent", function () {
    Y.log("This should, but won't appear despite how hard I try!");
});
```

Try:

```
this.on("*:testEvent", function () {
    Y.log("This should, but won't appear despite how hard I try!");
});
```

Or set .NAME on your Slide class (which you should do anyways):

```
Slide.NAME = "Slide";
```

And then your prefix uses that value:

```
this.on("Slide:testEvent", function () {
    Y.log("This should, but won't appear despite how hard I try!");
});
```

Using Y.Base.create will cut out a large amount of the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you why it fails when a plain JS-Object and a Y.Widget have to interact, while it works with two plain JS-Objects.

However, extending [Y.Base](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/base/) will fix your issue, while giving you full advantage of the power of Y.Base:

```
function Slide(config)
{
    Slide.superclass.constructor.apply(this, config);
}

Slide.NAME = "slide";

Y.extend(Slide, Y.Base, {

    initializer : function() {
               this.publish("testEvent", {
                  emitFacade: true//you do not need to specify this, 
                                  //it will be set implicitly to true
                                  //when using Y.Base
                });
            },
    test : function(arg) {
        this.addTarget(arg);
        this.fire("testEvent");
    }
});
```

The important thing here is the NAME-Attribute - it will become the prefix for your widget to listen for:

```
Y.extend(SlideShow, Y.Widget, {
    initializer: function() {   
       Y.log("Widget loaded!");
       this.on("slide:testEvent", function () {
            Y.log("This will work!");
        });

       this.on("*:testEvent", function () {
            Y.log("This will work, too no matter what's the Event's prefix!");
        });

       this.on("Slide:testEvent", function () {
              Y.log("This won't work, since the prefix doesn't match the NAME-Attribute!");
        });
    },
    //rendering etc.
});
```

In renderUI you'll call:

```
renderUI: function(){
    var testSlide = new Slide();
    testSlide.on('testEvent', function(e) {
       Y.log('You can listen for testEvent without a prefix on a Slide-object.');
    });
    testSlide.test(this);//adds this Widget as the target for the testSlide. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

So I tried to go deepper and decouple the issue.

First, I've tested example from @Mitch - as expected it works! proof: http://jsfiddle.net/pqr7/hQBHH/3/

But what if Slide is plain object (not extended from Y.Base)? I've tested example from @brian-j-miller and it does not work. proof: http://jsfiddle.net/pqr7/hQBHH/4/

Then I run my firebug and dive into YUI source step-by-step. And now I know how it works in details!

Let us see on example with plain object Slide http://jsfiddle.net/pqr7/hQBHH/4/
When I do `this.fire("testEvent");` on plain object Slide, YUI internally call a lot of functions in chain and operates with event `type` which is string = `"testEvent"` (I call it "type" because in source code it's always saved on variable with name "type").
I found that event bubbles and rich your target (instance of SlideShow) as expected.
Then it checks if SlideShow has some subscribers for event with `type` == `"testEvent"`? Answer: no!

If you make a subscription within SlideShow as `this.on('testEvent', ...)` its actually stored as string `type` == `"SlideShow:testEvent"`

If you make a subscription within SlideShow as `this.on('*:testEvent', ...)` its actually stored as string `type` == `"*:testEvent"`

If you make a subscription within SlideShow as `this.on('Slide:testEvent', ...)` its actually stored as string `type` == `"Slide:testEvent"`

But what is bubbled: is simple `type` == `"testEvent"`, so there is no subscribers inside SlideShow instance.

Then, YUI checks more complex rules with `*:testEvent`. Unfortunatelly our simple string `testEvent` do not match the pattern `*:testEvent`
Here is the original code http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/event-custom_js_event-target.js.html#693

`if (type.indexOf(PREFIX_DELIMITER) > -1) { /* make a magic to execute a subscriber */ }`

`type` here is our bubbled string `testEvent` and it does not contain PREFIX_DELIMITER (which is colon)

And this is the difference when you extend Slide from Y.Base - firered event would not a simple `testEvent` but `Slide:testEvent` and it mathes the pattern `*:testEvent` (http://jsfiddle.net/pqr7/hQBHH/3/)